# regular expression to match words with space or no space

Tags: php

i am trying to find php regular expression that match the word like "Hello World" with space and also match the word "HelloWorld" without space.

Comment: Well "Hello World" are two words... What do you want to match? What if string was "Hello there wonderful world"? You want to match complete sentence?

Comment: for example "Hello World" coming from variable like $search = "Helloworld"; and this $search search from string like $string = "Helloworld hi Hello world"; then how to match both word "Helloword" and "Hello world" from $string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
/^Hello ?World$/
```

Or you don't care the number of spaces:

```
/^Hello *World$/
```

Or it could also be blank chars like tab, then use `\s` instead a space.

Comment: but what if Hello World coming from variable?

Comment: @user3736833 What do you want to achieve?

Comment: for example "Hello World" coming from variable like
$search = "Helloworld";
and this $search search from string like 
$string = "Helloworld hi Hello world";
then how to match both word "Helloword" and "Hello world" from $string

Answer (score 1):

Generally that would be:

```
/[a-zA-Z ]+/
```

If you want numbers, too:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+/
```

You would need to set some sort of boundary. If the string just contains this, you can use start and end delimiters:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```